# how to add other than jar or zip files to any projects buildpath in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to know how to add other than jar or zip files to any projects buildpath in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Select project --> Properties --> Java Build path --> In the "Source" tab , expand your project and double click "Included" and add the files of your own , say *.xxx files..

Comment: The default setting is that everything is included (Included: All, Excluded: None). So no need to set it.

Comment: I don't know if it the classpath is generated with mvn eclipse:eclipse and some of them are excluded !!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add them to an existing source folder or add a dedicated folder to the build path (Context Menu for the folder > *Build Path* > *Use as Source Folder*) containing the files.

You can also add single files the same way (Context Menu for the file > *Build Path* > *Add to Build Path*).